# Plotting dataset with non-numerical axis

Tags: julia, gadfly

I have a dataset like this:

```
| Name  | 2017 | 2018 |
-----------------------
| Alice |  12  |  15  |
| Bob   |  11  |  10  |
```

I want to plot it with horizontal stacked bar chart such that on the Y axis I have Alice and Bob and on the X axis there are numbers from the table (Alice's bar has 12 and then 15-proportional length, similarly for Bob).

I tried to get data for 2017 first, so I did

```
using DataFrames, Gadfly
df = readtable("a.csv")
plot(df, x="2017", Geom.bar)
```

where `a.csv` is

```
Name,2017,2018
Alice,12,15
Bob,11,10
```

But I got

> Error showing value of type Gadfly.Plot:
>
> ERROR: UndefVarError: unshift! not defined

I also tried

```
plot(df, x="2017", y="Name", Geom.bar)
```

And got

> Error showing value of type Gadfly.Plot:
>
> ERROR: MethodError: no method matching zero(::Type{String})

Here the problem seems to be with the fact that the data on Y axis is non-numeric.

I have Julia 0.6.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
df_tr = stack(df, [:x2017,:x2018])
Gadfly.plot(df_tr, color = "variable", x="value", y="Name",
             Geom.bar(position=:stack, orientation= :horizontal))
```

i got something like this:

[image]

Comment: This is close towhat I need, thanks! Any way to stack 2018 bars on top of corresponding 2017's?

Comment: try to reverse their order in the dataframe ! hth

Comment: Two comments: 1) `unstack` in your code doesn't seem to do anything (its result is not assigned to anything and it is not !'ed, so have no side effects), so let's remove it; 2) just changing `:dodge` to `:stack` make the diagram stacked, just as requested in the question. So if you could fix these two issues, I'd approve the answer.

Comment: The chart does not reflect the changes in the code, but well…